# Sorting algorithm to find best options with multiple value constraints

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find out which sorting/algorithm would work best for the following case. I played around with Knapsack Unbounded (using https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/sets/knapsack-problem) but with no luck as practically it maximizes a value while here I am trying to limit all values under specific constraints. I believe it is a sorting one but would appreciate any suggestions and if any code samples available out there would be appreciated:

---

I have thousands of objects (food items), each with 4 values: "serving_calories", "serving_carbs", "serving_fats" and "serving_proteins". So it represents how much 1 serving of that food item represents.

The goal is to come up with 3-6 random options (with variable number of servings for each, which could be an increment of 0.5) where the constraints are predefined for each value for the totals. The numbers can have +-10% margin each (so a range for each value works).

Example: generate a collection of options that have a total of: 2000 calories, 250 carbs, 90 fats, 100 proteins. Based on the sample dataset below:

- **3 servings of food id "33597"**: 3 *
  ["serving_calories":418.62,"serving_carbs":38.58,"serving_fats":19.78,"serving_proteins":22.32]
  = [1255.86, 115.74, 59.34, 66.96]

  **2.5 servings of food id "39383"**: 2.5 * ["serving_calories":295,"serving_carbs":53.55,"serving_fats":3.81,"serving_proteins":16.31]
  = [737.5, 133.875, 9.525, 40.775]

  **1 servings of food id "33602"**: 1 *
  ["serving_calories":175.26,"serving_carbs":10.81,"serving_fats":14.23,"serving_proteins":5.29]
  = [175.26, 10.81, 14.23, 5.29]

**Totals: [2168.62, 260.425, 83.095, 113.025]**

Here is a sample set:

```
[
{"id":35583,"serving_calories":368.26,"serving_carbs":2.31,"serving_fats":24.51,"serving_proteins":32.46},
{"id":35584,"serving_calories":441.75,"serving_carbs":9.68,"serving_fats":30.23,"serving_proteins":33.65},
{"id":33595,"serving_calories":145.22,"serving_carbs":11.14,"serving_fats":1.5,"serving_proteins":22.77},
{"id":35421,"serving_calories":450.5,"serving_carbs":4.42,"serving_fats":19.64,"serving_proteins":60.68},
{"id":33596,"serving_calories":223.43,"serving_carbs":25.08,"serving_fats":10.57,"serving_proteins":9.1},
{"id":33597,"serving_calories":418.62,"serving_carbs":38.58,"serving_fats":19.78,"serving_proteins":22.32},
{"id":35200,"serving_calories":254.85,"serving_carbs":42.39,"serving_fats":9.8,"serving_proteins":2.88},
{"id":36130,"serving_calories":283.29,"serving_carbs":37.02,"serving_fats":6.42,"serving_proteins":19.23},
{"id":34522,"serving_calories":198.17,"serving_carbs":27.62,"serving_fats":5.67,"serving_proteins":9.52},
{"id":34520,"serving_calories":246.1,"serving_carbs":11.68,"serving_fats":5.44,"serving_proteins":36.63},
{"id":34521,"serving_calories":341.36,"serving_carbs":6.79,"serving_fats":13.73,"serving_proteins":45.06},
{"id":35215,"serving_calories":545.11,"serving_carbs":21.4,"serving_fats":23.89,"serving_proteins":59.96},
{"id":35219,"serving_calories":320.6,"serving_carbs":23.33,"serving_fats":8.66,"serving_proteins":35.12},
{"id":35423,"serving_calories":530.92,"serving_carbs":11.23,"serving_fats":45.07,"serving_proteins":23.49},
{"id":33599,"serving_calories":254.77,"serving_carbs":5.61,"serving_fats":11.91,"serving_proteins":29.32},
{"id":33601,"serving_calories":381.62,"serving_carbs":0.06,"serving_fats":33.58,"serving_proteins":18.52},
{"id":33600,"serving_calories":453.39,"serving_carbs":21.36,"serving_fats":28.08,"serving_proteins":37.38},
{"id":33598,"serving_calories":461.71,"serving_carbs":2.94,"serving_fats":36.56,"serving_proteins":28.46},
{"id":33602,"serving_calories":175.26,"serving_carbs":10.81,"serving_fats":14.23,"serving_proteins":5.29},
{"id":33604,"serving_calories":419.9,"serving_carbs":3.96,"serving_fats":20.04,"serving_proteins":53.89},
{"id":35557,"serving_calories":385.59,"serving_carbs":12.71,"serving_fats":31.72,"serving_proteins":16.39},
{"id":33603,"serving_calories":340.76,"serving_carbs":20.46,"serving_fats":20.09,"serving_proteins":20.29},
{"id":34526,"serving_calories":310.4,"serving_carbs":56.17,"serving_fats":3.6,"serving_proteins":13.41},
{"id":34528,"serving_calories":242.02,"serving_carbs":14.69,"serving_fats":5.81,"serving_proteins":32.03},
{"id":34537,"serving_calories":280.2,"serving_carbs":49.62,"serving_fats":5.94,"serving_proteins":11.37},
{"id":34538,"serving_calories":163.07,"serving_carbs":21.87,"serving_fats":5.91,"serving_proteins":5.66},
{"id":34539,"serving_calories":600.74,"serving_carbs":85.38,"serving_fats":21.93,"serving_proteins":18.71},
{"id":34529,"serving_calories":360,"serving_carbs":19,"serving_fats":7.97,"serving_proteins":50.96},
{"id":34543,"serving_calories":297.14,"serving_carbs":71.11,"serving_fats":1.46,"serving_proteins":6.73},
{"id":34544,"serving_calories":175.81,"serving_carbs":39.55,"serving_fats":1.29,"serving_proteins":5.75},
{"id":34524,"serving_calories":303.22,"serving_carbs":50.98,"serving_fats":6.49,"serving_proteins":14.6},
{"id":34540,"serving_calories":158.86,"serving_carbs":23.37,"serving_fats":4.29,"serving_proteins":8.51},
{"id":34523,"serving_calories":214.32,"serving_carbs":12.01,"serving_fats":13.68,"serving_proteins":14.16},
{"id":34546,"serving_calories":257.98,"serving_carbs":23.03,"serving_fats":12.04,"serving_proteins":16.01},
{"id":34541,"serving_calories":276.11,"serving_carbs":8.89,"serving_fats":16.14,"serving_proteins":22.76},
{"id":34542,"serving_calories":259.44,"serving_carbs":62.27,"serving_fats":1.25,"serving_proteins":6.17},
{"id":34552,"serving_calories":193.64,"serving_carbs":15.54,"serving_fats":15.07,"serving_proteins":3.74},
{"id":34553,"serving_calories":95.64,"serving_carbs":7.12,"serving_fats":7.08,"serving_proteins":3.3},
{"id":34554,"serving_calories":136,"serving_carbs":18.67,"serving_fats":4.75,"serving_proteins":6.29},
{"id":34555,"serving_calories":166.37,"serving_carbs":29.32,"serving_fats":5.28,"serving_proteins":2.73},
{"id":34567,"serving_calories":255.83,"serving_carbs":15.96,"serving_fats":5.94,"serving_proteins":35.3},
{"id":34566,"serving_calories":198.57,"serving_carbs":11.49,"serving_fats":6.09,"serving_proteins":25.3},
{"id":34572,"serving_calories":140.96,"serving_carbs":16.35,"serving_fats":0.9,"serving_proteins":17.8},
{"id":34573,"serving_calories":706.69,"serving_carbs":85.51,"serving_fats":25.4,"serving_proteins":38.96},
{"id":34574,"serving_calories":103.24,"serving_carbs":7.16,"serving_fats":4.81,"serving_proteins":8.49},
{"id":34571,"serving_calories":460.52,"serving_carbs":6.26,"serving_fats":22.07,"serving_proteins":57.63},
{"id":34576,"serving_calories":118.85,"serving_carbs":32.18,"serving_fats":3.33,"serving_proteins":8.18},
{"id":35246,"serving_calories":197.04,"serving_carbs":1.91,"serving_fats":10.23,"serving_proteins":24.7},
{"id":35465,"serving_calories":221.95,"serving_carbs":35.28,"serving_fats":4.95,"serving_proteins":10.15},
{"id":39383,"serving_calories":295,"serving_carbs":53.55,"serving_fats":3.81,"serving_proteins":16.31},
]
```

Comment: Sounds like a classic [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem problem). I've seen at least one github repo with a JavaScript LP solver.

Comment: Thanks! Will go ahead and try playing around with it.